# mathcad values of the Laplace integral function

Tags: mathcad

if I want to get the tabular value of the laplace function, how should I write it in mathcad?
for example  0.34 and i need 0.1331

(i don't nedd something like this)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to notice that the laplace is not a function. It is an integral transform. It means you can take result of transform and put it in function

[image]

And then get result for your input. It work even for direct placing

[image]

P.S. if I understood question right.